# eclipse error represented by a small question mark attatched to file icons

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

what causes files and folders in eclipse to have a tiny question mark attatched to them? also there is a label besides the project name that announces "[NO HEAD]". What does it mean?
[image]

Comment: is it actually linked to a repository? do you have a versioning plugin active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both things are related to [Git](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide):

- `[NO HEAD]` means that the project is contained in a new **Git repository where nothing has been committed yet** and therefore there is **no branch yet**.
- Files with `?` have **not** yet been **added** (to the staging area) in Git.

The first commit creates the *master* branch and turns `[NO HEAD]` into `[master]`. Since `[NO HEAD]` is the technically correct term, but misleading, newer EGit versions display `[master]` even before the first commit. So obviously, you are using an outdated version. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).